# Proper/clean way of setting up UIImage animation?

Tags: ios, swift, animation

First post, hi guys :)

I am building my first project and Im trying to make the code clean and organized. My app is a weather app and part of my app is a checkmark animation that plays when the weather is fetched.

To do this animation you i am declararing the images in the beginning, but it looks really messy and its many lines of code for just a simple thing.

I want to get in to the habit of creating organized code and am seeking advice on the correct way to organize code like this.

Relevant parts of my code looks like this:

Declaration:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import CoreLocation

// Animation setup

var loading_00040: UIImage!
var loading_00041: UIImage!
var loading_00042: UIImage!
//and many more like this
```

And in the viewController:

```
// Animation setup

    @IBOutlet weak var animationView: UIImageView!
    var checkmarkImages: [UIImage]!

    func setupAnimation(){
        loading_00040 = UIImage(named: "loading_00040.png")
        loading_00041 = UIImage(named: "loading_00041.png")
        loading_00042 = UIImage(named: "loading_00042.png")
        //and many more

        checkmarkImages = [loading_00040, loading_00041, loading_00042, loading_00043, loading_00044, loading_00045, loading_00046, loading_00047, loading_00048, loading_00049, loading_00050, loading_00051, loading_00052, loading_00053, loading_00054, loading_00055, loading_00056, loading_00057, loading_00058, loading_00059, loading_00060, loading_00061, loading_00062, loading_00063, loading_00064, loading_00065, loading_00066, loading_00067, loading_00068, loading_00069, loading_00070, loading_00071, loading_00072, loading_00073, loading_00074, loading_00075, loading_00076, loading_00077, loading_00078, loading_00079]
    }

    func playCheckmarkOnce(){

        animationView.animationImages = checkmarkImages
        animationView.animationDuration = 1
        animationView.animationRepeatCount = 1
        animationView.startAnimating()
    }

    func playCheckmarkAnimation(){
        setupAnimation()
        playCheckmarkOnce()
    }
```

And then i play it from the success case in a fetchWeather type method with a call to self.playCheckmarkAnimation()

After refactor:

I tried to put all this code in a seperate file called Animations.swift, using "class methods". It looks like this and is working great:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

var loading_00000: UIImage!
var loading_00001: UIImage!
var loading_00002: UIImage!
var loading_00003: UIImage!
var loading_00004: UIImage!
var loading_00005: UIImage!
var loading_00006: UIImage!
var loading_00007: UIImage!
var loading_00008: UIImage!
var loading_00009: UIImage!
var loading_00010: UIImage!
var loading_00011: UIImage!
var loading_00012: UIImage!
var loading_00013: UIImage!
var loading_00014: UIImage!
var loading_00015: UIImage!
var loading_00016: UIImage!
var loading_00017: UIImage!
var loading_00018: UIImage!
var loading_00019: UIImage!
var loading_00020: UIImage!
var loading_00021: UIImage!
var loading_00022: UIImage!
var loading_00023: UIImage!
var loading_00024: UIImage!
var loading_00025: UIImage!
var loading_00026: UIImage!
var loading_00027: UIImage!
var loading_00028: UIImage!
var loading_00029: UIImage!
var loading_00030: UIImage!
var loading_00031: UIImage!
var loading_00032: UIImage!
var loading_00033: UIImage!
var loading_00034: UIImage!
var loading_00035: UIImage!
var loading_00036: UIImage!
var loading_00037: UIImage!
var loading_00038: UIImage!
var loading_00039: UIImage!
var loading_00040: UIImage!
var loading_00041: UIImage!
var loading_00042: UIImage!
var loading_00043: UIImage!
var loading_00044: UIImage!
var loading_00045: UIImage!
var loading_00046: UIImage!
var loading_00047: UIImage!
var loading_00048: UIImage!
var loading_00049: UIImage!
var loading_00050: UIImage!
var loading_00051: UIImage!
var loading_00052: UIImage!
var loading_00053: UIImage!
var loading_00054: UIImage!
var loading_00055: UIImage!
var loading_00056: UIImage!
var loading_00057: UIImage!
var loading_00058: UIImage!
var loading_00059: UIImage!
var loading_00060: UIImage!
var loading_00061: UIImage!
var loading_00062: UIImage!
var loading_00063: UIImage!
var loading_00064: UIImage!
var loading_00065: UIImage!
var loading_00066: UIImage!
var loading_00067: UIImage!
var loading_00068: UIImage!
var loading_00069: UIImage!
var loading_00070: UIImage!
var loading_00071: UIImage!
var loading_00072: UIImage!
var loading_00073: UIImage!
var loading_00074: UIImage!
var loading_00075: UIImage!
var loading_00076: UIImage!
var loading_00077: UIImage!
var loading_00078: UIImage!
var loading_00079: UIImage!

var checkmarkImages: [UIImage]!

class Animations{

    class func setupAnimation(){
        loading_00040 = UIImage(named: "loading_00040.png")
        loading_00041 = UIImage(named: "loading_00041.png")
        loading_00042 = UIImage(named: "loading_00042.png")
        loading_00043 = UIImage(named: "loading_00043.png")
        loading_00044 = UIImage(named: "loading_00044.png")
        loading_00045 = UIImage(named: "loading_00045.png")
        loading_00046 = UIImage(named: "loading_00046.png")
        loading_00047 = UIImage(named: "loading_00047.png")
        loading_00048 = UIImage(named: "loading_00048.png")
        loading_00049 = UIImage(named: "loading_00049.png")
        loading_00050 = UIImage(named: "loading_00050.png")
        loading_00051 = UIImage(named: "loading_00051.png")
        loading_00052 = UIImage(named: "loading_00052.png")
        loading_00053 = UIImage(named: "loading_00053.png")
        loading_00054 = UIImage(named: "loading_00054.png")
        loading_00055 = UIImage(named: "loading_00055.png")
        loading_00056 = UIImage(named: "loading_00056.png")
        loading_00057 = UIImage(named: "loading_00057.png")
        loading_00058 = UIImage(named: "loading_00058.png")
        loading_00059 = UIImage(named: "loading_00059.png")
        loading_00060 = UIImage(named: "loading_00060.png")
        loading_00061 = UIImage(named: "loading_00061.png")
        loading_00062 = UIImage(named: "loading_00062.png")
        loading_00063 = UIImage(named: "loading_00063.png")
        loading_00064 = UIImage(named: "loading_00064.png")
        loading_00065 = UIImage(named: "loading_00065.png")
        loading_00066 = UIImage(named: "loading_00066.png")
        loading_00067 = UIImage(named: "loading_00067.png")
        loading_00068 = UIImage(named: "loading_00068.png")
        loading_00069 = UIImage(named: "loading_00069.png")
        loading_00070 = UIImage(named: "loading_00070.png")
        loading_00071 = UIImage(named: "loading_00071.png")
        loading_00072 = UIImage(named: "loading_00072.png")
        loading_00073 = UIImage(named: "loading_00073.png")
        loading_00074 = UIImage(named: "loading_00074.png")
        loading_00075 = UIImage(named: "loading_00075.png")
        loading_00076 = UIImage(named: "loading_00076.png")
        loading_00077 = UIImage(named: "loading_00077.png")
        loading_00078 = UIImage(named: "loading_00078.png")
        loading_00079 = UIImage(named: "loading_00079.png")

        checkmarkImages = [loading_00040, loading_00041, loading_00042, loading_00043, loading_00044, loading_00045, loading_00046, loading_00047, loading_00048, loading_00049, loading_00050, loading_00051, loading_00052, loading_00053, loading_00054, loading_00055, loading_00056, loading_00057, loading_00058, loading_00059, loading_00060, loading_00061, loading_00062, loading_00063, loading_00064, loading_00065, loading_00066, loading_00067, loading_00068, loading_00069, loading_00070, loading_00071, loading_00072, loading_00073, loading_00074, loading_00075, loading_00076, loading_00077, loading_00078, loading_00079]
    }

    class func playCheckmarkOnce(inImageView imageView: UIImageView){

        imageView.animationImages = checkmarkImages
        imageView.animationDuration = 1
        imageView.animationRepeatCount = 1
        imageView.startAnimating()
    }

    class func playCheckmarkAnimation(inImageView imageView: UIImageView){
        setupAnimation()
        playCheckmarkOnce(inImageView: imageView)
    }

}
```

Is this the proper way of organizing code like this or is there any better way? If anyone has any good resources id be very grateful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of all of those global variables. You don't need any of them. Just use a loop.

```
var checkmarkImages = [UIImage]()

func setupAnimation() {
    for i in 40...79 {
        let filename = String(format: "loading_%05d", i)
        if let image = UIImage(named: filename) {
            checkmarkImages.append(image)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What a great idea! Cheers :)

Comment: Glad to help. Please don't forget to accept answers that solve your issue.

Comment: Even more great advice! Thanks bro ill be sure to do that :)